# Using jQuery $(document).ready() in JavaScript Object Model

Tags: jquery, jsom

I've been using with great success the

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    FunctionName();
});
```

in a SharePoint WebPart code snippet to fire off COSM CAML queries using JavaScript to build various html outputs from a SharePoint list. Works great. But now I need to run three functions when the page loads. So I used the used the following but only the first function runs. I can switch positions of the function names but the first one will run. Thought it would be a no brainer. Silly me. Thoughts?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    FunctionName1();
});
$(document).ready(function() { 
    FunctionName2();
});
$(document).ready(function() { 
    FunctionName3();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It appears that I need to move away from the jQuery to the SharePoint standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to stack asynchronous calls so that the second function only executes when the first is complete.

Look into jQuery deferreds, they allow you to do exactly this: [api jquery com](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Take this as an example:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Init");

function Init() {
    Func1().done(function() {
        Func2().done(function() {
            Func3().done(function() {
                // All three functions with asynchronous calls now completed in order successfully
            });
        });
    });
}

function Func1() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: //url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // Do something with data if you want to
            dfd.resolve();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Do something with data if you want to
            dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return dfd;
}

function Func2() {
    // Exactly as Func 1
}

function Func3() {
    // Exactly as Func1
}
```

First `Func1` will execute. Only when the ajax call  has returned successfully will `Func2` then execute. If `Func1`'s ajax call failed `Func2` will not be executed. This is what the deferred object's `resolve` and `reject` functions ensure.

As you'll see in the link above, if you want `Func2` to execute regardless of the result of `Func1`'s ajax call then use the `always` method in place of `done`.

So the effect of the above code will be first `Func1` begins and completes, *then* `Func2` begins and completes, *then* `Func3` begins and completes.

If you have a requirement to wait for the ajax calls from `Func1` and `Func2` to return successfully (*in any order*) before making the ajax call in `Func3`, you can do this:

```
function Init() {
    $.when(Func1(), Func2()).done(function() {
        Func3();
    });
}
```

If there is no dependency on one function running before another then your `Init` function just needs to look like this:

```
function Init() {
    Func1();
    Func2();
    Func3();
}
```

With this, although each function will be executed in order, the result of each one's asynchronous ajax calls could return in any order.

A note about `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`. This is SharePoint's version of jQuery's `$(document).ready`. It ensures all SharePoint related elements are loaded.

Comment: Not my original intent, but I can see how this can be very useful. Current I using the functions to pull from a list to build a JumboTron, then pull from three separate lists to build a left, middle and right column. I'll try these ideas out and see how they work.

Thanks

Comment: Garurravs,
I looked this over and this appears will work find as it will allow the passing of parameters. Currently I'm not at the point of parameter passing but move very quickly to the light at the end of the tunnel. One of the leap out at me questions with SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction); was how to pass parameters and you have the answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Document ready event gets fired when the DOM get loaded. This doesn't necessarily guarantee that the JS files required for SharePoint JSOM is already loaded.

The best way is

```
 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', readyFunction);

function readyFunction() {
    Function1();
    Function2();
    Function3();
}
```

Comment: You the man!! I was just runing them in a series:

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Function1);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Function2);
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', Function3);

But this method failed if code was in a different webpart column, ie, the body and a nav. Your method works so yes I agree it is a better way.

Comment: Spoke to soon. Only work if I "hard reload" ie F5(refresh) Opening the page from a link fails to run the code. I have the run code in a code snippet at bottom of page. Then body column of the page template has function1 which build content and in the Right column is a funtion that builds a quicklink list. They run sepearatly but not unison unless a hard load the page F5.

Any ideas why and how to correct?

Comment: Are the JS code in different files? Before executing each function check if previous functions are executed with the help of a flag variables. If the variable is false then invoke functions from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I should of mentioned that it runs in Chrome without the need of a hard reload - page loads and both run. Not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one $(document).ready in your html but jquery provides another way to handle this for multiple function calls on page load. Use this:

```
$(function(){
function1();
function2();
function3();
});
```

Here

```
$(function(){
...
});
```

is equivalent to `$(document).ready` but the advantage is that you can call more than one function from within it or you can even declare it multiple times, once for each function call separately and all functions will be called as soon as the page loads as follows:

```
$(function(){
function1();
});

$(function(){
function2();
{);
```

Try it once.

Answer (score 0):

Example on coderwall about use `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()`:

https://coderwall.com/p/_jothq/jquery-when-to-use-document-ready-and-when-window-load